# Xamarin Android Properties -- Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I get the following error:

[image]

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="5" 
android:versionName="1.5" package="com.MarcusStudio.RecipeDatabase" android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:label="Recipe Database" android:icon="@drawable/icon"></application>
</manifest>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android:label="Recipe Database" needs to not contain a space.

Comment: It won't let me until tomorrow. I'm waiting patiently.